# Using django and chart.js to create a matrix heatmap showing crime over a range of dates. Can't drill down into a week cell and get the tooltip value

Tags: django, matrix, heatmap

I have a django template that uses script.js to create a webpage that produces a matrix heatmap I want to create an alert that shows the value of the tooltip for any cell in the matrix chart. Heres a sample of the data that has the tooltips:

{"type": "matrix", "options": {"aspectRatio": "5", "plugins": {"legend": false}, "scales": {"y": {"type": "time", "offset": true, "time": {"unit": "year", "round": "year", "parser": "yyyy", "displayFormats": {"year": "yyyy"}}, "reverse": true, "position": "right", "ticks": {"maxRotation": 0, "autoSkip": true, "padding": 1, "font": {"size": 9}}, "grid": {"display": false, "drawBorder": false, "tickLength": 0}}, "x": {"type": "time", "position": "bottom", "offset": true, "time": {"unit": "week", "round": "week", "parser": "w", "displayFormats": {"week": "ww"}}, "ticks": {"maxRotation": 0, "autoSkip": true, "font": {"size": 9}}, "grid": {"display": false, "drawBorder": false, "tickLength": 0}}}}, "data": {"datasets": [{"data": [{"x": "1", "y": "2020", "z": 0, "tooltip": "2020W01: 0 crimes"}, {"x": "1", "y": "2021", "z": 9, "tooltip": "2021W01: 9 crimes"}, {"x": "1", "y": "2022", "z": 4, "tooltip": "2022W01: 4 crimes"}, {"x": "1", "y": "2023", "z": 1, "tooltip": "2023W01: 1 crimes"}. . . . 


 
    function clickHandler(event) {
        const tooltipElement = document.querySelector('.chart-tooltip');
 

       // Get the clicked cell.
        const clickedCell = event.target;

        // Get the value of the tooltip.
        const tooltipValue = tooltipElement.textContent;

        // Display the tooltip below the clicked cell.
        tooltipElement.textContent = tooltipValue;
        tooltipElement.style.display = 'block';
        tooltipElement.style.top = `${clickedCell.offsetTop + clickedCell.offsetHeight}px`;
        tooltipElement.style.left = `${clickedCell.offsetLeft}px`;
    }

    // Add a click event listener to the cells in the matrix heatmap chart.
    document.querySelectorAll('#crime-list .cell').forEach(cell => {
        cell.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    });

I can get an alert('Clicked!') to work in any cell I click, but not much else. I have only been coding in Django/Python for a little less than a year, so I'm sure this is trivial, but not to me. I turn to the pros for edification.

I have tried Bard, Bing and Phind for solutions. None of their suggestions have worked.

Comment: I made a video that demonstrates what we are doing. The next step is when an officer clicks on a cell in the matrix, it will bring up an offcanvas window that shows the crimes within the cell, the week and year and a map of the selected crimes. Here is the video link https://drive.google.com/file/d/14dcd439WMPloyJTDuHA9yPEBuqF-rd6I/view?usp=drive_link